# Cannot compile ARM Kernel Windows 10 Driver

Tags: visual-studio, arm, windows-10, kernel, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile a Windows 10 Driver in ARM but I get this error when I try to compile with no error code. I have all of the individual components installed for my version of VS. (2019)

> The 'Desktop' target platform is not supported by the target OS
>   'Windows10' (0xA000007) for 'ARM'

Please help me resolve this,
thanks in advance

Edit:
The kernel driver is a socket server to communicate with another usermode application

Comment: See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/building-arm64-drivers)

Comment: I can't find either individual component "Visual C++ compilers and libraries for ARM" and "Visual C++ compilers and libraries for ARM64"

Comment: For VS 2019, they are "MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ ARM build tools (v14.23)" and "MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ ARM64 build tools (v14.23)". WDK for Windows 10, version 1903 is required for VS 2019 support. Often WDK support is a bit lagging...

Comment: I already have both components and WDK installed https://imgur.com/7jKlyNs

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  I'm having the same problem. I can compile ok for ARM64, but for ARM I get the same error you posted.

Comment: I never solved it, I just decided not to use ARM lol